# Causal consistency with Mongo 4.2.1 and Go driver 1.1.2

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm seeing some violations of "read what you wrote" with Mongo 4.2.1 and Go driver 1.1.2

This is on my development machine (Ubuntu), there is no cluster, just a single database, and it's quite small (hundreds of documents if that).

It has plenty of memory (32 gigabytes) and a fast disk (NVME). The file system is ext4 (I know XFS is preferred for performance, but there is barely any load here).

What happens is: one GO coroutine issues an update of a small document, setting a integer (Number) to a new value.

A second or so later, another thread does a read and does not see the write. Sometimes.

Repeating the read a few seconds later will then properly read back the new value.

Both threads (GO coroutines) use the same Mongo connection.

I tried to configure a read and a write concern like below, even though it's my understanding that "majority" is the default for both. It did not help.

```
readConcern := readconcern.Majority()

writeConcern := &writeconcern.WriteConcern{}
writeConcern = writeConcern.WithOptions(
   writeconcern.WMajority())

mongoConn, mongoErr := mongo.Connect(mongoCtx, &options.ClientOptions{
   Hosts:        []string{"localhost"},
   ReadConcern:  readConcern,
   WriteConcern: writeConcern})
```

From reading the docs*, I'm not clear if casual consistency should be automatically enabled for Mongo 3.6 or newer, or if it's something that needs to be enabled by the application or the driver.

If the latter, how do I enable casual consistency with the official GO driver?

[*] https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#sessions

Comment: Could you create a mcve? client sessions and write concern are not related to the usecase with a standalone db. It would be great to see the code to confirm you are waiting for write operation to complete before trying to read.

Comment: Alex, my code on the update side is like this:

 res, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(),
  bson.M{"_id": folder.Id},
  bson.M{
   "$set": values,
  },
 )

Comment: Alex, 
Re: "confirm you are waiting for write operation to complete before trying to read"

Sorry how do I do that?

I thought casual consistency meant that Mongo would guarantee that a read that "happens after" a write would see the write's effects, automatically? Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: That's right but only if your guarantee your reads "happen after" the writes. That's why I asked to see how you sync your gouroutines. Mongo knows nothing about them. It's your job to ensure read requests are sent to the db after write requests. Then the db will guarantee the consistency on its side - the reads will see results of writes.

Comment: Re: It's your job to ensure read requests are sent to the db after write requests.

Ah thanks. Yes my reads are after my writes, first it's how the code is structured and second there are logging Printf's which I see in the terminal window.

How can I check if casual consistency is in fact enabled?

Comment: I would enable oplog to confirm the order of requests on the db side agrees with what you se in the console on the client. "How the code is structured" - that's exactly what I am asking to check. Goroutines are not real threads after all. Casual consistency is enabled from v3.6 (with fCV 3.6+) for all queries within the same session. A standalone db instead of replicaset significantly simplifies data logistic and should be consistent anyway. If it the issue is reproducible I'd report it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on a mcve, no luck so far. I'll double check my concurrency but there actually is a fairly good (1/2 second or so) delay between the write and the read: post-write, the code sends a network message to a "client" and the client then comes back over http which performs the read.

Comment: Receiving stale data after 500 millis on an idle standalone database is quite unusual. It cant be because of concurrency alone. It would be great if you can extract and share the minimal code that reproduces it.

Comment: I keep trying with the minimal code, nothing yet. In my real project the failure is more likely to occur if just prior to the "bad" section, there is also data being inserted (to a different collection).

I also added "sanity check" code to read back the just updated values immediately after UpdateOne with FindOne - and when the larger failure occurs (between two coroutines), the sanity check also fails.

More details if you could read this please:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-go-driver/Y-AA_hjzMpU/D6rlfbVCBAAJ

And thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Causal Consistency requires the use of explicit session. Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/

Comment: Thank you Wan I think this was the missing piece.

Comment: @WanBachtiar - Seems I can make the issue go away by using readConcern = Local

Is this an appropriate fix if I'm interested in SQL-like behavior, where a read that starts after a write has completed is guaranteed to see the results of that write?

I'm having trouble finding answers in the docs which seem to focus a lot on replication and multi-node installations.

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev I don't think `readConcern` local guarantees the behaviour that you desired. Without an mcve to look into, it's quite hard to tell how your co-routines guarantees order of execution in itself.